# Xamarin Studio and PortableRest

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, restsharp

So i try to create a little android project with Xamarin Studio and i faced with a problem. Earlier i used to use RestSharp library to easy sending http-requests. But this library is not supported in pcl projects in xamarin. Instead tis library i was using PortableRest library. It looks like RestSharp. But on the first run i got an exception with the following message "Could not load file or assembly System.Net.Http.Primitives". How can i fix this error? or maybe are there another libraries working with pcl projects?

Answer (score 0):

Try [HttpClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http) from Microsoft.